# How to send POST requests containing an XML array in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml, rest

I'm trying to have the ability to receive a post request through rest contains an array of XML, if I post individually it works fine, but I tried to post an array it says:

> Error in line 1 position 140. Expecting element.

My goal is to have the ability to receive array or individual and post them in SQL.

Here is the XML formation I want: also if I can remove the xmlns would be great but I don't know how:

```
<ArrayOfT_persons xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RestDataAccess">
<T_persons>
  <Name>jhon</Name>
  <DATETIME>2019-07-29T15:51:41.2540564+03:00</DATETIME>
  <GRADE>A</GRADE>
  <AGE>16</AGE>
</T_persons>
<T_persons>
  <Name>Will</Name>
  <DATETIME>2019-07-29T15:51:41.2540564+03:00</DATETIME>
  <GRADE>C</GRADE>
  <AGE>18</AGE>
</T_persons>
</ArrayOfT_persons>
```

and here is the post method

```
[ResponseType(typeof(T_persons))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostT_persons(T_persons t_persons)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.T_persons.Add(t_persons);

    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        if (T_personsESExists(t_persons.NAME))
        {
            return Conflict();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = T_persons.NAME }, t_persons);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely answer, you need a List of TPersons:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostT_persons(List<T_persons> t_persons)
{ 
   ...
}
```

At a glance, the object should be named TPerson, as well (ideally, not from what you have shown:

```
List<TPerson> TPersons;
```

Where the object would look something like:

```
public class TPerson
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public DateTime DateTime {get; set;}
    public char Grade { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok how to add them individually inside the db

Comment: That to me would be a second question, @AshmedMear since you seem to be focusing on the Post method here... And SO is about QA to answer google-able question... But it should be essentially : `TPersons.Foreach(e => { db.T_persons.Add(e) }); db.Save(); `